# Hammer to fake zoom not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I have a little "pdf"-viewer to use in the iPad. Since I found that rendering PDF in HTML is painfully slow, I tried to go with a PNG solution. Since it's a webapp and everything is pixel -perfect, zoom is disabled.

My idea was to create sort of a "window" which is in fact a div that encapsulates an image, no matter how big it is. So far so good.

However, I decided to try Hammer to emulate the pinchin pinchout and something weird happens. When you pinchin or out, the page seem to shake and then you're not able of doing nothing else... However, if you add an alert on the event handler (yes, an alert) it works as expected.

This is the code:

```
(function($){
  var pdfViewer = {
    pdf: {},
    currentPage : 1,
    currentZoom : 200,
    defaultZoom : 200,
    intervalZoom : 30,
    el : {
      pdfWindow : $('.pdf-window'),
      image : $('.pdf-window').find('img')
    },
    init : function(){
      this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents : function(){
      var self = this;
      this.el.pdfWindow.hammer().on('pinchin',function(e){
        self.currentZoom = self.currentZoom - self.intervalZoom;
        self.updateZoom.apply(self);
      });
      this.el.pdfWindow.hammer().on('pinchout',function(e){
        self.currentZoom = self.currentZoom + self.intervalZoom;
        self.updateZoom.apply(self);
      });
    },
    updateZoom : function(){
      this.el.image.attr('width',this.currentZoom + '%');
    }
  };

  pdfViewer.init();
})(jQuery);
```

And this is a clean demo. You should try in an iOS device... Any ideas of what can be wrong?

Bug demo: http://jsbin.com/ivixov/1/quiet

Comment: Where are you placing the alert? It sounds like you might have an issue with two pieces of code trying to do conflicting things at the same time, and the alert is currently the means by which you're preventing this.

Comment: @pandavenger I place the alert inside the event handlers. Doesn't make really sense and the code is really straightforward as you can see.

Comment: Tell me if adding any of these to the events will help. You might need to prevent iPad default behaviors such zooming by itself.

https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Event-delegation-and-how-to-stopPropagation---preventDefaults

Comment: I'll try but the iPad default behaviour won't happen at all since I have this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: So you're able to get the `alert` to fire *then* the zoom works? or you replaced the zoom *with* an `alert` instead?

Comment: No, @couzzi if I put an alert just inside the handler function without removing anything, everything works... but with an ugly alert

Comment: Instead of an `alert`, try wrapping in a `setTimeout(function(){...},0)`. I know how ridiculous that sounds, but I had a funny feeling it will work.

Comment: Hi @couzzi I had the same feeling... Didn't work... I scratch my head trying to figure why the alert makes it work and that's what came to mind and didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried manipulating `meta viewport` parameter to get the zoom working? eg. inside iframe?

Answer (score 0):

On my ipad 1, iOS 5.1 it works as expected. My guess is pinch events are too sensitive and called many-many times per pinch-move, but alert preventing them to happen cuz it pauses a code execution after first pinch event fires. I suggest you to modify `pinchin` event like this:

```
this.el.pdfWindow.hammer().on('pinchin',function(e){
    self.currentZoom = self.currentZoom - self.intervalZoom;
    if(self.currentZoom < 0) self.currentZoom = 0;
    self.updateZoom.apply(self);
});
```

And try to decrease `intervalZoom`

But I think the better idea is to use `pinch` event and work with `event.gesture.scale` parameter